# Question about words ending with `glia` or `lia` (or `glio` or `lio`)

Tags: difference, pronunciation

Novice Italian-language speaker here, so apologies for the elementary question, which is as follows.

What is the difference between pronouncing (e.g.) the words `Puglia` and `Pulia` (contrived)? I ask because it seems that `Italia` and `Itaglia` (contrived) are seemingly pronounced the same – is this the case?

As another example, what's the difference betwixt pronouncing `imbroglio` and `imbrolio`?

**EDIT**: My issue is that the words `figlia` and `Italia` sound the same, whereas `Modugno` and `moduno` (contrived) are clearly different.

Comment: The “gli” sound is quite difficult for foreigners, but really distinct from “l”. Some Italian people are not able to pronounce “gli”, but would never substitute “l” for it, they'd rather use something similar to the “l mouillé” of French.

Comment: You have to extend your tongue to cover the lateral lower teeth and genlty press the upper teeth over the tongue. The tip of the tongue points forward to almost touch the front teeth.

Comment: The following link may be of help: *How to Master the “R”, “GN” & “GLI” Sounds in Italian -*
http://icebergproject.co/italian/2014/03/how-to-master-the-r-gn-gli-sounds-in-italian/

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: If this may help, the “l” sound in “lio” is an [alveolar lateral approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_lateral_approximants), while the “gl” sound in “glio” is a [palatal lateral approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_lateral_approximant) (but the audio sample of the latter in the Wikipedia article is realised in a different way than how Italian uses it).

Comment: “the words figlia and Italia sound the same”: “glia” and “lia” do not at all sound the same. The pair “gno” and “no” is a good comparison, though, since here too the former is, broadly speaking, the palatal version of the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer, which does not address "how to learn to pronounce them" (for that, it would probably be best to find a guide/course/book aimed at your particular source language, in your case English, since the best way to learn how to pronounce them may be different depending on which language you come from).

They are definitely two different sounds. There are [minimal pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair) between them, for instance olio / [Oglio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oglio).

In IPA, gl -> /ʎ/ (often geminated /ʎʎ/), l -> /l/, the dialectal variant of gl mentioned by @egreg in a comment -> /j/.